# множественное копирование bash

Tags: bash

```
cp -r f1/  {f2/,f3/,f4/}
```

как с одной папки скопировать много с разными названиями ?

Comment: `alldir='/folder1/ /folder2/ /folder3/ /folder4/; for dir in $alldir; do cp -r /folder/ $dir; done`, при передаче cp нескольких каталогов возникает ошибка: `cp: задано несколько целевых каталогов`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант без использования цикла:

```
echo f2/ f3/ f4/ | xargs -n 1 cp -r f1/
```

Утилита `xargs` принимает на вход поток вывода от команды `echo` и отправляет его как аргументы в команду `cp`, запуская для каждой группы из одного параметра (т. е. для каждого параметра) отдельный процесс копирования.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in {2..4}; do cp -r f1 "f$i"; done
```